# static function variable vs static class variable

Tags: php, oop, php-7.2

Consider the following:

```
class Super
{
    static protected $class_var = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        static $function_var = 0;

        static::$class_var++;
        $function_var++;

        echo sprintf("class_name : %s, class_var : %s, function_var : %s\n", static::class, static::$class_var, $function_var);
    }

    public static function test()
    {
        static $function_var = 0;

        static::$class_var++;
        $function_var++;

        echo sprintf("class_name : %s, class_var : %s, function_var : %s\n", static::class, static::$class_var, $function_var);
    }
}

class A extends Super {}
class B extends Super {}

echo "Object calls\n";
new A();
new A();
new B();
echo "Class calls\n";
A::test();
A::test();
B::test();
```

PHP 7.2.7 ouputs:

```
Object calls
class_name : A, class_var : 1, function_var : 1
class_name : A, class_var : 2, function_var : 2
class_name : B, class_var : 3, function_var : 3
Class calls
class_name : A, class_var : 4, function_var : 1
class_name : A, class_var : 5, function_var : 2
class_name : B, class_var : 6, function_var : 1
```

Why do A and B have their own static function var when called on the class. Whereas A and B share the static function var when called on instances. Or more general, how do they exactly work internally?

Comment: How about you not use global variables at all?

Comment: @tereško that's the programmers spirit i was hoping for

Comment: I am actually serious. If you use a "static class" it's actually just a list of namespaced global functions (because, before 5.3 there was no namespacing) and the static variables are essentially just an alternative form of global state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general behaviour can be explained like this (there's a proviso below about constructors): static class properties are scoped against the class in which they are *defined*, and static method variables are scoped against the class for which they are *called*.

The fact your `test` method is declared as static isn't important here, so I've cut this down into the following test script:

```
class Super
{
    static protected $class_var = 0;

    public function test()
    {
        static $function_var = 0;

        static::$class_var++;
        $function_var++;

        echo sprintf("class_name : %s, class_var : %s, function_var : %s", static::class, static::$class_var, $function_var), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class A extends Super {}
class B extends Super {}
```

Because it's *defined* on the class, `$class_var` will always be linked to that scope. However many classes extend `Super`, they'll refer to the same variable (unless they override it).

`$function_var` on the other hand, is scoped to the class(es) in which the `test` method is *called*. Calls to all instances of `A` will share one, and calls to all instances of `B` will share one.

```
$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->test(); // class_name : A, class_var : 1, function_var : 1
$a->test(); // class_name : A, class_var : 2, function_var : 2
$b->test(); // class_name : B, class_var : 3, function_var : 1
```

## Constructors (A Proviso):

The other issue in your question is that the constructor behaves differently to any other class method, because despite being syntactically similar, it isn't a method at all. Similar to class properties, any variable declared static in the constructor is scoped to the class in which it's *defined*:

If we add in:

```
public function __construct()
{
    static $constructor_var = 0;
    $constructor_var++;

    echo sprintf("class_name : %s, constructor_var : %s", static::class, $constructor_var), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Then we can demonstrate as follows:

```
$a = new A; // class_name : A, constructor_var : 1
$b = new B; // class_name : B, constructor_var : 2
```

Unless any of the subclasses override the constructor, they'll all share the same instance of `$constructor_var`.

I can't find a nice simple summary of any of this in the documentation unfortunately, and I'm also not sure how much of it is by design at all. Static variables in a constructor especially aren't something I think I've ever come across, and static function variables are increasingly rare themselves. But it's interesting to know how things work, so good question.

Comment: hey @iainn, thx for the answer! I was using the static method var for singletons:
https://www.tehplayground.com/Wob6CNZF8wtm3Iue
For this behaivour, static method var seemed the only solution.

Comment: Don't use static, don't use singletons. Stop this madness. Embrace dependency injection.

Comment: @emix singletons vs DI <==> apples vs pears

Comment: Sorry, but no. Write proper OOP, SOLID, testable, maintainable code.